Data streaming pdf-lib to bind large number of images into a single pdf using JS (or Rust) with Tauri 2.0
I'm trying to make a simple Tauri app that takes a folder of images and binds them into a PDF in batch. During development, I encountered a problem where the program could not handle a pdf instance with many images (above 500 MB).
When the program processes a large image, I get the following warning:
IPC custom protocol failed, Tauri will now use the postMessage interface instead

and the app will crash with the error:
unexpected invoke body

This issue is consistent with the problem mentioned in https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/6866. However, in my case, I used pdf-lib to process the imaging bindings, but, that library requires me to explicitly initialize a PDF file and keep it in memory, which will grow until it crashes if the images are too large (the line with the issue https://github.com/hoonsubin/img-to-pdf-converter/blob/master/src/helpers/index.ts#L73)
I think data streaming could solve this issue, but I'm not entirely sure how to use data streaming using Tauri 2.0 with TypeScript since the fs API does not support file streaming. (and the library isn't optimized for it either).
I found out about the lopdf crate in Rust, which sounds promising, but I'm not an experienced Rust dev, and from my limited knowledge, lopdf and other PDF crates on Rust still function similarly to the JavaScript (TypeScript) packages, in that it requires the program to fully load the entire PDF file in memory before saving it to disk. I've also considered sideloading Node.js with Tauri, but the fundamental issue was still the same (albeit with more liberty with memory management and file streaming).
I see great solutions using C#, Java, or Python, but I have yet to find a solution using TypeScript (without Node.js) or Rust.
Is there a way to write a PDF file in chunks using pdf-lib TypeScript or Rust to handle massive PDF size?

@KJ I see. Thank you for your response. I take that this is a non-trivial problem. I'll have to search for more 'creative' ways to handle this. I'll keep the thread posted!
